# Recipe manager for iOS

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I am looking for a recipe manager for my iPod Touch and my requirements are:

1. It must not require online registration and it must be fully functional offline (it's okay if it has "cloud" features, but they must not be required)
2. It must be either free, or under $3 (I don't do a lot of cooking—I just have some favorite recipes I would like to keep handy—and I'm not willing to invest too much)
3. Of course, it must allow me to add my own recipes

I don't really need in-app features like shopping list management, timers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I use [PlainText](http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/plaintext) it's free, with a $2 in-app upgrade to remove the ads if you don't like them.

I find that plain text is easy to store (search!) and share my recipes with. I use it on iPad and iPhone and have a reasonable collection of recipes on there. The Dropbox sync makes it easy to add existing recipes from other sources, or to back up.

Comment: I do have PlainText, and I've considered using it for recipes.

Answer (score 1):

What about **Notes**? It ships with iOS, and you can use it to store notes about anything, including recipes.